# (click) action does not work inside of [innerHTML] Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 6. I have a variable named `chatConversations` that I add html codes in to it. And in front-side I show data by this code:

```
<div [innerHTML]="_DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(chatConversations)"></div>
```

The problem is in some of HTML codes that I`m injecting into it, I have some click action like :

```
<span (click)="doSomething">do it</span>
```

But it does not work when I inject it into the `chatConversations`. How can I make functional the (click) elements that I inject into the [innerHTML]?